# How to get form data in bidi ring handler?

Tags: forms, clojure, request, ring, bidi

I am trying to access the form data in `bidi.ring` handler. A form submission is associated to a `bidi.ring` handler and I am not able get the form data in the request.

In some blog I found`form-params` is the one. But the request object does not have this at all. I have also checked `params` `route-params`. All are `nil`.

For reference:

```
(defn index-handler [request]
  (if (= (:request-method request) :post)
   (let [title (get (:form-params request) "title")]
     (println title))))

(defn handler []
  (make-handler ["/" {"" index-handler}]))


(defrecord HttpServer [server]
  component/Lifecycle
  (start [this]
    (assoc this :server (http/start-server (handler) {:port 8080}))) ...)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have no further middleware setup.  You need at least [`wrap-params`](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/blob/6b8d49196a1d4dd254e7905d63c19c7f5729439d/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/params.clj#L33-L55).  See the [docs of bidi](https://github.com/juxt/bidi#wrapping-as-a-ring-handler) for details how to do so.

Comment: Thanks @cfrick . That's exactly what I was missing